# "No overload matches this call" in Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript

I was doing an Angular tutorial, when I ran into the following error in the `home.component.ts` file:

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 5, '(observer?: PartialObserver<HttpResponse>): Subscription', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(data: any[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PartialObserver<HttpResponse>'.
> Property 'complete' is missing in type '(data: any[]) => void' but required in type 'CompletionObserver<HttpResponse>'.
> Overload 2 of 5, '(next?: (value: HttpResponse) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(data: any[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: HttpResponse) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'data' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'HttpResponse' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

I have looked it up, but have been unable to find any solutions to this issue.  I have tried to to disable `strict`, `noImplicitAny`, `noImplicitReturns` in the `tsconfig.json`, but they have not solved this issue.  I would prefer if there was a solution to this issue while keeping all three settings on `true` in the `tsconfig.json` file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT:** The error occurs in the `home.component.ts` file when dealing with the data after the AJAX call:

```
this.dataService.sendGetRequest().subscribe(data: any[] => {
      this.products = data;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Never specify the types of callback parameters. `.subscribe((data: any[]) => ` is worse than pointless. Write `.subscribe(data => `

Comment: @AluanHaddad why is this the case? This is the way we were taught Angular/TypeScript back in 2017 when did this change?

Comment: @almcaffee it has never changed. It's always been bad a very bad practice to specify the types of callback parameters. Whoever taught you was wrong.

Comment: @AluanHaddad so what is the purpose of typescript if you aren't using types?

Comment: @almcaffee TypeScript is having type information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: it would be a courtesy if you put your relevant code in the question itself, instead of just the link to stackblitz. The first thing the error message gives you is: which file, which line, which position (`Error in src/app/home/home.component.ts (19:49)`). Which is

```
    this.dataService.sendGetRequest().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
//                                              ^ about here
```

Second: you put `observe: "response"` in your HttpClient call. Well, in such case you won't get simply `data: any[]` in your response object, but a whole `HttpResponse` object.  You need to access its `body` property. I suggest adding

```
map({ body } => body)
```

at the end of the pipe in `sendGetRequest` in `DataService`.

Comment: First, yes you are correct.  I should have put the relevant code in the question.  I apologize for that.  With regards to adding a map at the end of the pipe, do you mean chaining it on pipe? Sorry, but I am new to RxJS.  Thanks.

Comment: @MA_Dev yes, just add the `map` as the last operator, after `retry`, `catchError` and `tap`.

Comment: I did the following, but it returns ```undefined```: 

```return this.httpClient.get(this.REST_API_SERVER, { params: new HttpParams({fromString: "_page=1&_limit=20"}), observe: "response"}).pipe(retry(3), catchError(this.handleError), tap(res => {
      this.parseLinkHeader(res.headers.get('Link'));
    }), map(res => {
      res.body
}));```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `map(res => { res.body })` - if you write it like this, the JS engine interprets the `{}` as delimiters of the function body (and it doesn't have an explicit return statement). Either `map(res => { return res.body; })`, or simply `map(res => res.body)`.

Comment: It worked.  Thank you very much.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: i did not understand where should i put map({ body } => body)

Answer (score 7):

Solution: change `any[]` to `any` in the `subscribe` method as so;

```
this.dataService.sendGetRequest().subscribe(data: any => {
      this.products = data;
    });
  }
```

Comment: What if I did not want to use any?