# What's the problem with this code in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and typescript, so I watched youtube videos and copid them to understand what is going on.
[Youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/E-GA9GKJWuE?t=7369)

This is in the component I'm trying to subscribe as in the video. And this is the line I get an error saying:

> Error: src/app/components/prof-btn/prof-btn.component.ts:34:43 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 5, '(observer?: NextObserver | ErrorObserver | CompletionObserver | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(users: User[]) => Users[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NextObserver | ErrorObserver | CompletionObserver | undefined'.
> Property 'complete' is missing in type '(users: User[]) => Users[]' but required in type 'CompletionObserver'.
> Overload 2 of 5, '(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(users: User[]) => Users[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'users' and 'value' are incompatible.
> The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
> Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Users[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

> 34     this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((users: User[]) => this.users = users);

> node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts:64:5
> 64     complete: () => void;
> 'complete' is declared here.

`ngOnInit() {this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((users: User[]) => this.users = users);}`

userService

`getUsers() {return this.webService.get('users');}`

webService :

``` get(uri: string) {this.http.get(``${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}``);} ```

Here i'm subscribing to a service which is sending me back

The program is working correctly, so its getting me the data, but I'm curious what is the problem?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/65861049/8563549

Comment: Did you return the statement as well from the Webservice like this:get(uri: string) {return this.http.get(``${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}``);}

Answer (score 1):

```js
get(uri: string) {this.http.get(``${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}``);}
```

should be

```js
get(uri: string) {return this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`);}
```

You need the `return` statement in the `get` method of your Webservice and there is a mistyping error: You have two `` instance of one.